# TextAppearance property of TextView in Android

Tags: android, textview

I am working on android application where I am using `TextView` to display the text on screens.

I am using this property for the `TextView` to set the size of the text `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"`.

Do I need to set the size of that text also or it does automatically manage by Android OS ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a default.  If you want to change it, then yes, you need to put in the code.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Does it mean if I use `android:textAppearance` and set my text size manually also ?

Comment: Try it.  Why load a browser, login, type a bunch of text, submit it, wait... instead of just trying it -- and doing all that if there's a problem?  If you've done all that, then post the code so someone can provide targeted help.

Comment: @JeremyMiller I got my answer from your first comment but still one doubt that I asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237616/textappearance-property-of-textview-in-android#comment37433925_24237616

Comment: Ok, that was funny... I did click the link... and I ended up here... so... the doubt... is... (waiting with baited breath)

Comment: @Williams if you want use `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"` you don't need for changing size, android take care that in all display.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Can you post your answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Posting now... Got lost in some other code.

Comment: android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" will automatically adjust the medium size text in android. You no need to set text size .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android text elements there is a default which is applied first (similar to webpages).  If you wish to override those and define your own, then you must explicitly set them. `android:textAppearance` is one such override, but there are other attributes you can override  individually (as opposed to as an aggregate)... you'll want to see the documentation for that.

Comment: I see you still did not answer "Does it mean if I use android:textAppearance and set my text size manually also ?"

Comment: I don't understand that last question (this in the comments).  Can you briefly demonstrate?

Comment: I mean If I set this `android:textAppearance` to `TextView` and set the text size also to same `TextView` using setText(15) then here any use of using property `android:textAppearance` ?

Comment: Whichever is set last, I believe will override the previous values.  There's only a "use" in doing so if you intend to override.  So, for example, a text by default is 24sp and then on a specific case you want it 36sp.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, the resizing is done automatically in the background.

While using attributes like `android:textAppearance` it directly uses the predefined specific sp values for the textSize as:

```
android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" => 14sp

android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" => 18sp

android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" => 22sp
```

Thus it adjusts the values automatically based on the *screen density* and the *user's preference* in such a way that it seems equal on all the devices say for example formula for dp values:

**px = dp * (dpi/160)**

The similar case is for the sp values used only for fonts, it utilizes the same concept only difference being it may vary due to user's fontSize preference as set in settings.

I haven't used that `:attr/` type as it may or may not be used and serves the same purpose because the system resource tool knows that an attribute resource is expected in this context, you do not need to explicitly state the type.

Answer (score 4):

> Do I need to set the size of that text also or it does automatically manage by Android OS ?

Nope, Using `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium` will make all of the text in medium size on different devices. So that means your app text on different devices will have the same size and weight.

Setting the size of each text would require calculation to be able to achieve same size and weight.

Comment: Are you sure that it would have same text size to all android density if I use android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium ?

Comment: @Williams yes.. rather than setting the text size.. here a code when you want to set txt size for all different devices. textSize=factor*height

Comment: But I think Android defined different values of text size according to the density `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium `

Comment: @Williams yes different dpi values but the same effect/size on different device

Comment: why some tablet not support fully textappearance

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I think that using textAppearanceMedium just is same in deference density and not deference size of device.