# Why EditText only accepts Theme?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme, android-styles

I was trying to apply a `style` to an `EditText` to change it's `colorAccent`, I tried to set its `style` and `android:textAppearance`, but it completely ignored my new settings. The only way I got it to work was by setting its `android:theme`.

Am I doing something wrong or is this expected behavior? Why?

My style:

```
<style name="bright_color_cursor" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryBrightColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/primaryBrightColor</item>
</style>
```

My `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:theme="@style/bright_color_cursor"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/hello"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name_edit_text"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider" />
```

Changing `android:theme` to any of this settings won't work:

```
style="@style/bright_color_cursor"
```

or

```
android:textAppearance="@style/bright_color_cursor"
```

Comment: "_Am I doing something wrong_" If you post your code/xml we might be able to tell...

Comment: Lol, I this this easy to reproduce, my code is as straight as I say in my post, but it you want it, ok.

Comment: Ok, I just placed my code, as I said, its very straightforward...now people downvoted it so much I doubt I will get any answers out of it :/

Comment: For `android:style`, the value needs to be a style resource that extends a TextAppearance: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes. `android:textAppearance` expects an attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237616/textappearance-property-of-textview-in-android

Comment: isn't it just `style`?

Comment: I extendend my entire `AppTheme` I thought it would have some text styles inside it as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this behavior is to be expected with an EditText. We need to style it by using the `android:theme` property.

When using `@style`, the EditText doesn't use the values that we set (and thus the style *seems* to be ignored). This is, because the EditText creates some children views that are not being styled. See my detailed explanation below.

---

**Detailed explanation and the cause**

1) First, the meanings of the options tried and what these do:

- `style`: (Note: not prefixed with `android:`): This sets the styles **only** for the component itself and does **not** change the styles of it's underlying children views/layouts.
- `android:theme`: This basically applies to style to itself **and** applies the style to it's **children** views/layouts.
- `android:textAppearance`: This one behaves just like `@style` for styling.

2) The `EditText` functionality

As we can imagine: an EditText is not just a simple view. It has a background drawable and handles interaction and such. It simply needs some additional views (and logic) for this functionality to work.

For the functionality of the `EditText`, it **adds** some subviews as children to be able to do what we expect from it.

3) Back to theming

The subviews that the `EditText` adds to do it's functionality, are styled just like the other views are being styled. Which means that the child views only inherit the style when we use the `android:theme` property. Because this property causes it to style the children views too.

And, if we use `@style` on the edittext, the children **will not** get this style.

4) Why this happens (only) for EditText?

Well, not really *only*... The base view of an `EditText` is a `TextView`, but a `TextView` doesn't provide the functionality that an `EditText` needs. So the `EditText` adds additional functionality itself.

A `Button` for example has the `TextView` as base too. But this class has enough views with the text and background it gets from the base class, and thus a `Button` doesn't need to add additional views for it's functionality. So for this, using `@style` works as it creates no children views to style.

*Having said this, a small remark:
In fact, in the source the `TextView` actually contains the editting logic, but in case of a `Button` it simply doesn't execute that part of code. (A button doesn't need the `Editting` functionality, thus it's not being executed)*